# Parametric version of a simple equation

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric, plane-curves, curves, parametrization

I have a simple relation that I need to plot in a plane.  I could do it, but I believe that I don't get the best way.  A plane curve is defined implicitely by the following equation :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\cos{\chi} + \sin{\eta} = \sqrt{f} \; \cos{\eta},
\end{equation}
where $f$ is a positive constant.  I need to plot the curve in the $(\chi, \eta)$ plane.  It's easy to invert the relation above (expressing $\chi$ as a function of $\eta$ is simpler but isn't well adapted to the curve) :
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\sin{\eta} = g_f(\chi) \equiv \frac{\sqrt{f^2 + f \, \sin^2{\chi}} - \cos{\chi}}{1 + f},
\end{equation}
so I could define a parametric version of equation (1) above :
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
(\chi, \; \arcsin{g_f(\chi)}),
\end{equation}
This does the job.  However, I strongly suspect there's a simpler parametrisation of the same curve, represented by equation (1).

So the question is what is the best or simplest parametrisation $(\chi(s), \; \eta(s))$ of the equation (1) above ?

**EDIT :**  Take note that $\chi$ is only defined on the interval $-\pi$ to $\pi$.  Also : $-\frac{\pi}{2} < \eta < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: What did you get for $\cos \chi$ in terms of the rest? It seems one could use a trig identity to get the right side as a constant times a single sine or cosine, after leaving only the $\cos \chi$ term on the left.

Comment: @coffeemath, the curve is mostly horizontal in the $(\chi, \; \eta)$ plane.  So expressing $\chi$ as a function of $\eta$ doesn't do the job well.  It's better to have $\eta$ defined as a function of $\chi$ instead.  This is why I prefer to find a parametric expression of the curve.

Comment: By a shift of $\eta$, you can rewrite as the slightly simpler $\cos\chi=a\cos\eta$, where $a=\sqrt{1+f}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, how ?  the parameter $f$ could be anything, from 0 to infinity ; $0 < f < \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation can be rearranged to
$$
\cos\chi = \sqrt{f}\cos\eta - \sin\eta.
\tag{1}
$$
Let $\phi$ be an angle (unique up to an added integer multiple of $2\pi$) satisfying
$$
\cos\phi = \sqrt{\frac{f}{f + 1}},\qquad
\sin\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{f + 1}}.
$$
By the sum formula for cosine, (1) becomes
$$
\cos\chi
  = \sqrt{f + 1}(\cos\phi \cos\eta - \sin\phi \sin\eta)
  = \sqrt{f + 1} \cos(\phi + \eta).
$$
This can be written
$$
\eta = -\phi + \arccos\left(\frac{\cos\chi}{\sqrt{f + 1}}\right).
$$

Comment: @Cham note that $\tan \theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{f}}$ so $\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{f}}\right)$.

Comment: Using some trigonometric identities, the formula above for $\eta = -\phi + \arccos{\ldots}$ gives back the same thing as my formula (2) shown in my question.  So I don't think this solution is the parametric representation that I'm looking for.  Maybe there is no simpler parametric solution to my problem, but my intuition tells me there should be one.

Comment: Numerically, $\eta = -\phi + \arccos \cdots$ is simpler than $\eta = \arcsin g_{f}(\chi)$, though you're right that algebraically they're identical. As $f$ ranges over the positive reals, the resulting curves fill out the isosceles right triangle with vertices $(0, -\pi/2)$ and $\pm\pi, \pi/2)$. The fact the curves are graphs with $\eta$ a function of $\chi$ looks pretty nice. Is there a sense in which you don't find these parametrizations "simple"? (E.g., maybe you're looking to avoid inverse trig functions?)

Answer (score 1):

Using Andrew's answer, I could define the following parametrization, which appears to be working great :
\begin{align}
\big(\, \chi(s), \; \eta(s) \big) = \big(\arccos{s}, \quad \arccos{\frac{s}{\sqrt{1 + f}}} - \arccos{\sqrt{\frac{f}{1 + f}}} \big),
\end{align}
where $-1 < s < 1$ (or $s = \cos{\chi}$).  But I still suspect this could be improved (i.e. simplified).  That parametrization isn't much simpler than the expression (2) I gave in my question.

Comment: This is probably the worst parameterization you can think of, as it truncates the domain on both axis.

Comment: I forgot to say that $\chi$ is only defined on the interval $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Comment: ah, this was essential in the discussion.

Comment: I added that info to my question.